# Meaning of “segnare la misura”

Tags: idioms

Does anybody know the meaning of the idiom “*segnare la misura*” (apart from its literal meaning)?

I find it in a 1943 text about primary school curricula: «Si sconsiglia di attardarsi nel procedimento slegato degli insegnamenti artistici ..., dei canti ..., del disegno ..., di numeri e di calcoli di aritmetica, di cui l’esperienza e la volontà a progredire dei fanciulli non segni la misura».

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire paragraph?

Comment: Uhm, "segnare il passo" forse? Probabilmente "misura" qui si riferisce alla battuta musicale, per cui il significato sarà letteralmente del tipo "dare il tempo".

Comment: @leoredi: Unfortunately, I find this sentence quoted within an article that only gives what I wrote, ellipses include.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Grazie! E quindi il senso complessivo, secondo te, quale sarebbe? Se non ci fosse il “non” (“non segni la misura”) capirei meglio la tua idea sul “segnare il passo” nel senso di “essere costretti a fermarsi”.

Comment: @DaG: non saprei, secondo me la frase è stata tagliata troppo perché si capisca qualcosa, oltre al fatto che è un dedalo di doppie negazioni e perifrasi (l'autore andrebbe impiccato); la mia interpretazione era basata giusto sull'ultimo spezzone, ma rileggendo diverse volte la frase ora non ne sono più tanto convinto.

Comment: I agree with Matteo, it looks like it means "dare il tempo". so the meaning would be like "to give the pace".

Answer (score 5):

> **Si sconsiglia di attardarsi nel procedimento** slegato **degli insegnamenti** artistici ..., dei canti ..., del disegno ..., di numeri e di calcoli di aritmetica, **di cui l’esperienza e la volontà a progredire dei fanciulli non segni la misura**

"Segni la misura" in questo contesto probabilmente è da intendersi come "non sia misurabile", con la frase che in pratica starebbe a significare

> "Non perdere tempo su ambiti di insegnamento in cui i fanciulli sono inetti > (*l'esperienza*)o per cui non hanno interesse (*la volontà a progredire*)"

Comment: I think you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that in this case the intended translation of "segnare la misura" could be "being the meter for". That's because the sentence seems to be related to an education process that has not to be paced with the already acquired experience of a student, nor his/her will to progress in the subject. It's really tricky to evince that without a more detailed overview of the sentence background and context. It's written in Italian that was fancy in the late '30s, during Fascism, and the quote, unfortunately, is poorly taken from the original text.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, 'non segni la misura' means 'non comprenda la portata' there.